# Cast Graphics to Image in C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I have a pictureBox on a Windows Form.

I do the following to load a PNG file into it.

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("Image.PNG", true);
Bitmap tmp;

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tmp = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height), 0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

However, I need to draw things on the image and then have the result displayed again. Drawing rectangles can only be done via the Graphics class.

I'd need to draw the needed rectangles on the image, make it an instance of the Image class again and save that to `this.bm`

I can add a button that executes `this.pictureBox1.Refresh();`, forcing the pictureBox to be painted again, but I can't cast Graphics to Image. Because of that, I can't save the edits to the `this.bm` bitmap.

That's my problem, and I see no way out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is use the [Graphics.FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) method, which will allow you to draw directly on the image instead of the temporary `Graphics` object create from within the `Paint` method:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.bm))
{
    g.DrawRectangle(...);
}
```

Do this instead of (or in addition to) hooking the `Paint` method of the `PictureBox`.  This way, you won't need to use a temporary image or `Graphics` object at all, and when you're finished modifying the original bitmap (`this.bm`) then you can invoke `pictureBox1.Refresh` to force the image to be re-displayed.

Comment: I had been wondering why when I drew using e.Graphics in my Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) method the graphics were not part of the image.  Thanks for this tip on how to draw directly on the image!